# PHP - Push to array does not work

Tags: php

```
        <?php
    $avaliableLines = array();
    echo '<div class="dropdown">';
    echo '<button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Today Line
      <span class="caret"></span></button>';
    echo '<ul class="dropdown-menu">';
        foreach ($avaliableLines as $menuElements) {
            echo '<li><a href="#">'.$menuElements.'</a></li>';
        }
    echo '</ul>';
    echo '</div>';


    $urlSite = file_get_html('http://18130126.com/ubetportal/?clientId=137/');
    foreach ($urlSite->find('.ui-collapsible-content') as $element) {
        echo $element;
    }



    error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);

    //NBA y sus periodos
    $nbaAndPeriodos = file_get_contents('http://18130126.com//ubetportal/UbetWebIISFmxService.dll/datasnap/rest/TServerMethods1/GetData_League_Details/137/3/');
    $obj = json_decode($nbaAndPeriodos);
    echo $obj->result[0];
    if (!empty($obj->result[0])) {
       $avaliableLines[] = "NBA";
    };

    //College Basketball-Juego Completo y Primera Mitad
    $collegeBasketBall = file_get_contents('http://18130126.com//ubetportal/UbetWebIISFmxService.dll/datasnap/rest/TServerMethods1/GetData_League_Details/137/4/');
    $obj2 = json_decode($collegeBasketBall);
    echo $obj2->result[0];
    if (!empty($obj2->result[0])) {
       $avaliableLines[] = "College Basketball";
    };


    //NHL-Juego Completo y Primera Mitad
    $hockeyContent = file_get_contents('http://18130126.com//ubetportal/UbetWebIISFmxService.dll/datasnap/rest/TServerMethods1/GetData_League_Details/137/7/');
    $objHackey = json_decode($hockeyContent);
    echo $objHackey->result[0];
    if (!empty($objHackey->result[0])) {
       $avaliableLines[] = "NHL";
    };

    //Golf-Juego Completo
    $golfContent = file_get_contents('http://18130126.com//ubetportal/UbetWebIISFmxService.dll/datasnap/rest/TServerMethods1/GetData_League_Details/137/11/');
    $objgolf = json_decode($golfContent);
    echo $objgolf->result[0];
    // Si ay gold entonces agrega golf al menu del golf
    if (!empty($objgolf->result[0])) {
       $avaliableLines[] = "Golf";
    };
    //Tennis - Juego Completo
    $tennisContent = file_get_contents('http://18130126.com//ubetportal/UbetWebIISFmxService.dll/datasnap/rest/TServerMethods1/GetData_League_Details/137/12/');
    $objtennis = json_decode($tennisContent);
    echo $objtennis->result[0];
    if (!empty($objtennis->result[0])) {
       $avaliableLines[] = "Tennis";
    };

    //Italian Serie A leafue - Juego Completo y Primera Mitad
    $italianSerieContent = file_get_contents('http://18130126.com//ubetportal/UbetWebIISFmxService.dll/datasnap/rest/TServerMethods1/GetData_League_Details/137/24/');
    $objitalian = json_decode($italianSerieContent);
    echo $objitalian->result[0];
    if (!empty($objitalian->result[0])) {
       $avaliableLines[] = "Italin Serie";
    };


    //Spanish La Liga - Juego Completo y Primera Mitad
    $spanishContent = file_get_contents('http://18130126.com//ubetportal/UbetWebIISFmxService.dll/datasnap/rest/TServerMethods1/GetData_League_Details/137/25/');
    $objSpanish= json_decode($spanishContent);
    echo $objSpanish->result[0];
    if (!empty($objSpanish->result[0])) {
       $avaliableLines[] = "Spanish La Liga";
    };

    //Mexican Primera League - Juego Completo y Primera Mitad
    $mexicanContent = file_get_contents('http://18130126.com//ubetportal/UbetWebIISFmxService.dll/datasnap/rest/TServerMethods1/GetData_League_Details/137/29/');
    $objMexican = json_decode($mexicanContent);
    echo $objMexican->result[0];
    if (!empty($objMexican->result[0])) {
       $avaliableLines[] = "Mexican Primera League";
    };

    //French Ligue 1- Juego Completo y Primeta Mitad
    $frenchContent = file_get_contents('http://18130126.com//ubetportal/UbetWebIISFmxService.dll/datasnap/rest/TServerMethods1/GetData_League_Details/137/31/');
    $objfrench = json_decode($frenchContent);
    echo $objfrench->result[0];
    if (!empty($objfrench->result[0])) {
       $avaliableLines[] = "French Ligue";
    };


    //Boxing Ligue 1- Juego Completo y Primeta Mitad
    $boxingContent = file_get_contents('http://18130126.com//ubetportal/UbetWebIISFmxService.dll/datasnap/rest/TServerMethods1/GetData_League_Details/137/10/');
    $objboxing = json_decode($boxingContent);
    echo $objboxing->result[0];
    if (!empty($objboxing->result[0])) {
       $avaliableLines[] = "Boxing Ligue";
    };



     ?>
```

I want , for example if objets returns something so i want push into the array , but do no push nothing

so this is my code of everything .. when the statement if is done i want echo the element into a dropdown...

Comment: Try to use array_push($avaliableLines, "Tennis");

Comment: Please reduce your code to  minimal, viable script that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: I've just tested your code and it's working: ``array(3) {
  [0] =>
  string(18) "College Basketball"
  [1] =>
  string(3) "NHL"
  [2] =>
  string(6) "Tennis"
}
``  thats the output.

which version php do you have?

Comment: Is this actually what the code looks like in your file, in this order? You are using the array for your dropdown before you fill it...

Comment: @IdirOuhabMeskine is have to work i dont not why is not working PHP Version 5.6.30

Comment: @jeroen yes bro that is the original code i haved the codes like that and do not work , now is working because i was using the foreach loop before i fill it .

Comment: I suggest you, just for debugging purpose, to remove all the ``echoes`` and keep just the array push.

Just to troubleshoot, you could force the if condition to see if indeed the issue is related with the array or with the conditions.

Comment: Please try to separate your `PHP logic code` from your `HTML` markup it's a little bit cleaner and easier for debugging process.